# Useing Ant to build a Jar file WITH COMMENT

Tags: eclipse, ant, comments

I have a Jar build from my own project(using ANT),
my project have comments in java files,but when i use this Jar in new project,I can't see the comments（by press F2 in eclipse）,Some one said that I can't see comment unless i have the source file of the Jar.
The question is,is that true?or there's some other way to have comments with my Jar(without Source files)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments from your source code are not part of the compiled class files, so they will not be visible unless you provide the source java files

You can generate javadocs and include them with your jar library. There is a [javadoc ant taks](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html) to generate the javadoc. You can then either include it in your jar file, or provide it separately. If you include the javadoc inside the distributable jar, whoever is using your jar will have to either extract the javadoc out to view them, or specify that the jar file also contains the javadoc inside the IDE

Comment: thank you very much.    I followed your suggestion and generate the javadoc of my Jar, and how can i attach the htmls with the Jar?Further more,can i attach it to my Jar when i use ant build the Jar?

Comment: I believe this is being covered in your followup question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817483/can-i-save-comment-info-in-my-jar-filegenerated-by-ant

Comment: Thank you Alex.In my other question,I have not get a satisfied answer ether. In your Answer ,you point out if I have a Jar with javadoc in it ,I can specify the jar file also contains the javadoc,but in eclipse I have not find a way to do so...